# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number with list sum

Tags: python, list

I want to read txt file and sum all the list elements

```
with open('beautm.txt') as f:
    p = []
    for line in f:
        line = line.split()         
        line = [float(i) for i in line]
        p.append(line)

print p
print type(p)     
print sum(map(float,p))
```

That should be simple,but

```
[[729000.0, 243000.0, 81000.0, 27000.0, 9000.0, 3000.0, 500.0, 500.0], [500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0], [500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0], [500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0], [500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0], [500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0], [500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0], [500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0], [500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0], [500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0], [500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0], [500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0], [500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0], [500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0], [500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0], [500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0], [500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0], [500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0], [500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0], [500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0], [500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0], [3000.0, 9000.0, 27000.0, 81000.0, 243000.0, 729000.0]]
<type 'list'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mk4.py", line 10, in <module>
    print sum(map(float,p))
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

Comment: your p is list of lists, you should use .extend instead of append in your loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main issue here, appending a list into a list:

```
>>> p = []
>>> p.append(l)
>>> p
[[1, 2, 3]]
>>> p.append(l)
>>> p
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

So, as a fix to your code, use `list.extend` instead:

```
>>> p = []
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> p.extend(l)
>>> p
[1, 2, 3]
>>> p.extend(l)
>>> p
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `p` is a list of lists. Each element of `p` as a `line` which is constructed with list comprehension `[float(i) for i in line]`. So that's the reason why you cannot execute a `float` upon it

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned earlier, you are trying to apply `float` to a list. However I am not sure if you want the total sum or sum of every sublist. Either way:

If you want to sum everything across all lists you can chain them before summing:

```
from itertools import chain
print sum(map(float, chain(*p)))
```

If you want individual sums per list you can say something like:

```
print [sum(map(float, sublist)) for sublist in p]
```

For your `p` the output is as follows:

```
# Total sum
2265000.0
# Sums per each list
[1093000.0, 4000.0, 4000.0, 4000.0, 4000.0, 4000.0, 4000.0, 4000.0, 4000.0, 4000.0, 4000.0, 4000.0, 4000.0, 4000.0, 4000.0, 4000.0, 4000.0, 4000.0, 4000.0, 4000.0, 4000.0, 1092000.0]
```

If you do want the total, you could also change the `.append` line in your loop to this:
`p += line`

Answer (score 1):

Or you could do the summation in your loop and not build an unnecessary list:

```
with open('beautm.txt') as f:
    p = 0
    for line in f:
        line = line.split()         
        p += sum([float(i) for i in line])

print p
```